# How to make latency of QPushButton for push?

Tags: qt, user-interface, latency, qpushbutton

I would like to create QPushButton which gives an opportunity to press not often than one time in 200 msec. When I use func sleep(200) all GUI thread will stop.
Waiting for your ideas!
Thankx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    // ...
private:
    QPointer< QPushButton > btn;
private slots:
    void onClicked();
    void enableClick();
};

Controller::onClicked()
{
    disconnect( btn, SIGNAL( clicked() ), SLOT( onClicked() ) );
    QTimer::singleShot( 200, this, SLOT( enableClick() ) );
    // Optional
    btn->setEnabled( false );
}

Controller::enableClick()
{
    connect( btn, SIGNAL( clicked() ), SLOT( onClicked() ) );
    // Optional
    btn->setEnabled( true );
}
```